# Ruby On Rails Display Image

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am a newbie at it.I have just educated myself for 2 days. And a have a problem.

**Example:** I have a table , called as `tblData`, includes 2 columns: `id, img_link`. `img_link` contains link to an image.

I want to show all of them in this table(id and image, not image link) into a html file. 
So, exactly what I need do?

Comment: please show me stepbystep

Answer (score 0):

If you have an image link that you can pull from your database, you can do something like this:

Assuming you have an object assigned and everything's set up:

In your controller for tbl_data (e.g. app/controllers/tbl_data_controller.rb):

```
class TblDataController < ApplicationController
  def your_action
    @tbl_data_item = TblData.first
  end
end
```

(The code above is just an example, you should substitute for whatever code/query you wish to run)

In your view template, you can render an image from a link using the following Rails view helper:

```
<%= image_tag(@tbl_data_item.img_link) %>
```

This would output the following HTML:

```
<img src="/path/to/image/from/img_link" />
```

There's a lot more info on this helper on the [Rails api docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html#method-i-image_tag). The [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#getting-up-and-running) has some awesome info on getting things set up and running as well. Hope this helped!

**UPDATE:**
To give you a better example with clearer steps, you would do something like the following:

Set up your routes (app/config/routes.rb):

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :tbl_data
end
```

Create your model, used to communicate with its respective database table (app/models/tbl_data.rb):

```
class TblData < ActiveRecord::Base
  # your model-specific code goes here - validations, scopes, etc.
end
```

Create the controller, which responds to when a user hits a certain route in your app (app/controllers/tbl_data_controller.rb):

```
class TblDataController < ApplicationController
  def your_action
    @tbl_data_items = TblData.all
  end
end
```

Create the view template, that will be rendered for your user(app/views/tbl_data/your_action.rb):

```
<table>
  <% @tbl_data_items.each do |item| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= item.id %></td>
      <td><%= image_tag(item.img_link) %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

The above would show a table with each record in the `@tbl_data_items` as a row, with 2 columns, one with the id, and one with the actual image for that item.

Comment: which file will I put this line "@tbl_data_item = TblData.first"?

Comment: That line serves as an example only and is set inside your controller file for the tbl_data resource. Updated my answer to reflect this info. I also provided a link to the Rails Guides on getting started, which should give you the basics of how to set up the controller, model, routes and templates.

Answer (score 0):

Create a folder in public called images, put the desired image in that folder.

Put `<%=image_tag 'whatevertheimagefilenameis.png', class: 'example-class', id: 'example-id'%>` in the html.